# IBM ODM 8.10 : update existing dependencies on decision center when synchronizing

Tags: synchronization, ibm-odm

I developed two decision services (DS1 & DS2) in Rule designer, having the same dependencies artifacts (same name). When I synchronized with decision center for the first time DS1, dependencies were "loaded" to decision center. Then I made some changes to dependencies to able implementation of DS2. When I tried to synchronize with decision center, the dependencies were not updated. Only DS2 were updated. 
How can I synchronize independently each decision service (with its own dependencies) with decision center? without renaming artifacts.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ODM supports below Synchronization Command:
**Publish**:sends artifacts from Designer to Decision Center
**Update**: receives artifacts from Decision Center into Designer
**Override and Publish**: resolves conflict by replacing the Decision Center artifact with the Designer version
**Override and update**: resolves conflict by replacing the Designer artifact with the Decision Center version

Hope this Help.